# kernel compilation error during make modules_install

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I was trying to make my raspberry pi more Real-time and I use the `PREEMPT_RT`.But when `sudo make modules_install`, an error occurs.

Here are some information about the error.
Any help or suggestions welcome.Thank you~

```
cp: cannot stat ‘./modules.builtin’: No such file or directory
Makefile:1143: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 1
```

Comment: Which `defconfig` (or another configuration) you used? Have you performed `make` and `make modules` first? Have those commands finished without compilation/linking errors? Also, we would need to know which kernel tree you are trying to build (link/tag/branch).

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi: I first ensured the raspberrypi-kernel-headers package was installed; then in the module Makefile, I changed the line 'make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install' to 'make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules_install' and it now seems to work!?  The $(PWD) wasn't getting the pwd...